# Very long time is consume while Iterating First Array and fetching respective data from Second Array by matching ID in iOS Swift 4

Tags: arrays, swift, loops

I have one Array which has HotelId key & it's value like below

```
[
  {
    "StartPrice": 724.45,
    "HotelId": 2251800,
    "HotelOption": []
  },
  {
    "StartPrice": 725.05,
    "HotelId": 84357,
    "HotelOption": []
  }
]
```

now I have to iterate above array with below second array by matching it's HotelId & fetch respective data from the array

```
[
  {
    "HotelId": 5103,
    "HotelName": "Abc Hotel",
    "Rating": "3",
    "IsRecomondedHotel": false
  },
  {
    "HotelId": 5104,
    "HotelName": "Paradise Hotel",
    "Rating": "3",
    "IsRecomondedHotel": false
  },
  {
    "HotelId": 5105,
    "HotelName": "Hotel Sea Rock Inn",
    "Rating": "4",
    "IsRecomondedHotel": false
  }
]
```

Now the main problem is, it's working fine when first array count is normally 25-30 around, but takes usually **2-4 mins** when the **first array** count is **around 1050** & **second array** count is **around 5000** with below code

```
//
print("\n******************** final hotel list preparation starts ****************"
hotelListArr = [HotelListModel]()
if let hotelListDictArr = hotelListDict, // LOGIC 2
    let hotelMappingDictArr = hotelMappingDict {

    for hotelListItem in hotelListDictArr {

        for hotelMappingItem in hotelMappingDictArr {

            if let hotelIdInList = hotelListItem["HotelId"],
                let hotelIdInDetails = hotelMappingItem["HotelId"],
                "\(hotelIdInList)" == "\(hotelIdInDetails)" {

                let obj = HotelListModel()
                obj.setValuesForKeys(hotelListItem)
                obj.setValuesForKeys(hotelMappingItem)
                hotelListArr?.append(obj)
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
print("ends...\nhotelListArr.count: \(String(describing: hotelListArr?.count))")
```

With above approach gets result in Android Java around 5 seconds but in iOS Swift 4 same result takes 2-4 mins when array count is big,

**Could anyone help on this to how to perform above operation very fast in iOS Swift 4?**

Comment: Have you tried working with structured data (using struct or class) for the first array and storing the elements in a dictionary using hotel Id as key?

Comment: Your algorithm has exponential complexity. Convert `hotelMappingDictArr` to a dictionary first.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson can u please guide me with some sample link because I have some little bit confusion with your comment so